# How to place image to set border in dropdown bootstrap4

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap 4 navbar to create my menu. In my menu, I have a dropdown menu. I want to customize my dropdown top border, but problem is the top border will look like [image](https://simimaging.co.uk/wp-content/themes/theme1491_RWD/images/divider.png).

I am trying to add a png image with dropdown, so that the top border could change, but it's not looking like a border and it leaves some margin as well.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<style>
.dropdown {list-style: none; background: green; display: inline-block;}
.dropdown .nav-link {color:#fff; text-decoration: none;}
.dropdown .dropdown-menu a{color: #000; text-decoration: none;}
.dropdown .dropdown-menu{background-image: url("images/arrow.png"); background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 20px 20px;
 }
.dropdown .btn {background: green; color:#fff;}
.dropdown .btn:hover {background: cyan; color:#000;}
.dropdown .btn:active {background: cyan; color:#000;}
.dropdown .btn:focus {background: cyan; color:#000;}
 .dropdown-item {display: inline-block; width: 100%; padding: 10px 5px;}
.container .dropdown .dropdown-menu a:hover
{
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #b91773;
  border-color: #fff;
}
</style>

<body>

<div class="container">
  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
          aria-expanded="false">
  Dropdown link
</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used `100% 6px` in background-size property. Is this the desired output?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<style>
.dropdown {list-style: none; background: green; display: inline-block; }
.dropdown .nav-link {color:#fff; text-decoration: none;}
.dropdown .dropdown-menu a{color: #000; text-decoration: none;}
.dropdown .dropdown-menu{
    background-size: 100% 6px;
    background-image: url("https://simimaging.co.uk/wp-content/themes/theme1491_RWD/images/divider.png"); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
 }
  .dropdown-menu{
  margin-top:20px;
  border-top:none;}
.dropdown .btn {background: green; color:#fff;}
.dropdown .btn:hover {background: cyan; color:#000;}
.dropdown .btn:active {background: cyan; color:#000;}
.dropdown .btn:focus {background: cyan; color:#000;}
 .dropdown-item {display: inline-block; width: 100%; padding: 10px 5px;}
.container .dropdown .dropdown-menu a:hover
{
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #b91773;
  border-color: #fff;
}

.dropdown-item:nth-of-type(1) {
}
</style>

<body>

<div class="container">
  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
          aria-expanded="false">
  Dropdown link
</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks rv7. it is much nearer to my desired output. can i rotate this image 180 degree which point to dropdown. n i dont want border uder this image < . Thanks once again

Comment: @shreya_js You can rotate this image with some editing tools, it would be easier that doing it by css

Comment: but now problem is i want upward arrow beneath top dropdown item. and it will show only when it open

Comment: Check the update, now you can see the arrow beneath the top dropdown item

Comment: i need something below link...                                                 https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/bootstrap-mega-menu.  done

Comment: hi rv7, i upload an image with my query. please have a look. so that you find whats the problem..